# How to replace values of a columns of CSV in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, rscript

The code below is written in R shiny and currently reads data from the 'mtcars' database. This app was made to replace the specific data in a column., It has options such as 'Column to search' for selecting columns, "replace" and "By" for replacing values that the user specifies in the 'Replace' field. It is now working perfectly.

But what I really want is to use 'Browse' to upload my own csv data and perform the same operations as 'Replace' and 'BY'. How to accomplish this?

**Expected result:**

How can values be replaced? (from old to new values). as an example How should I modify the value 100 to 500 in the 'range' column by referencing the column name in the 'select column' from the below csv data?

**current csv:**

```
ID  Type  Category    Range
21  A1     B1          100
22  C1     D1          200
23  E1     F1          300
```

**Expected CSV results:**

```
ID  Type  Category    Range
21  A1     B1          500
22  C1     D1          200
23  E1     F1          300
```

**app.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File", accept = ".csv"),
         selectInput("col", "Column to search:", names(mtcars), names(mtcars)[1]),
         textInput("old", "Replace:"),
         textInput("new", "By:"),
         actionButton("replace", "Replace!"),
      ),
      mainPanel(
         DTOutput("table1")
      )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   my_data <- reactiveVal(mtcars)
   
   observeEvent(input$replace, {
      req(input$col)
      dat <- my_data()
      traf <- if (is.numeric(dat[[input$col]])) as.numeric else identity
      my_data(dat %>%
                 mutate(!!rlang::sym(input$col) := 
                           replace(!!rlang::sym(input$col),
                                   as.character(!!rlang::sym(input$col)) == input$old,
                                   input$new) %>% 
                           traf()))
   })
   
   output$table1 <- renderDT(
      my_data()
   )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: @RonakShah, I have updated my 'Expected CSV results' above.

Comment: @RonakShah,   The CSV I've shared here is only a portion of my larger CSV, which has over 100,000 records. I would like to use  to replace some values from the columns I have selected from `selectInput` (from a drop-down list that shows column names of the CSV)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the `fileUploader` logic to fill `my_data` accordingly:

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File", accept = ".csv"),
         checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
         selectInput("col", "Column to search:", NULL),
         textInput("old", "Replace:"),
         textInput("new", "By:"),
         actionButton("replace", "Replace!"),
      ),
      mainPanel(
         DTOutput("table1")
      )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   my_data <- reactiveVal(NULL)
   
   observeEvent(input$file1, {
      file <- input$file1
      ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
      req(file)
      validate(need(ext == "csv", "Please upload a csv file"))
      my_data(read.csv(file$datapath, header = input$header))
      updateSelectInput(session, "col", choices = names(my_data()))
   })
   
   observeEvent(input$replace, {
      req(input$col)
      dat <- req(my_data())
      traf <- if (is.numeric(dat[[input$col]])) as.numeric else identity
      my_data(dat %>%
                 mutate(!!rlang::sym(input$col) := 
                           replace(!!rlang::sym(input$col),
                                   as.character(!!rlang::sym(input$col)) == input$old,
                                   input$new) %>% 
                           traf()))
   })
   
   output$table1 <- renderDT(
      req(my_data())
   )
}
```